# In Mercurial, after hg merge, how to revert files marked 'U' and matching a pattern to a specific revision?

Tags: mercurial, merge

In Mercurial, after hg merge, how to revert files marked 'U' and matching a pattern to a specific revision?

After doing 'hg merge' I find a class of files matching a pattern and marked 'U' to be mistakenly merged and would like to revert them to the last version.  How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will revert unresolved text files back to the first parent of the merge.  Use `p2()` for second parent:

```
hg revert "set:*.txt and unresolved()" --rev p1()
```

You may then need this to clear the unresolved flag:

```
hg resolve --mark *.txt
```

**Edit**

Per your comments, I tested this command successfully on Windows:

```
hg revert "set:'re:[0-9]foobar.*\.txt' and unresolved()" -r "p1()"
```

Comment: What if the files I want to revert back is ONLY `*.txt` files match regex `[0-9]foobar.*\.txt`?  Where to learn more about `set` syntax?

Comment: Using `--rev p1()` gives error `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`('\``

Comment: I'm on Windows so it is your shell.  You may have to quote `"p1()"`.  Also see `hg help filesets`.